# Using Sushi on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, 19.04, previews, gnome-sushi

I try to use sushi (which offer similar feature like Quick Look on MacOS ) on Ubuntu 19.04.
Got this error:

```
(sushi-start:8478): Gjs-WARNING **: 15:07:50.705: JS ERROR: Error: Requiring Sushi, version none: Requiring namespace 'GtkSource' version '3.0', but '4' is already loaded
@/usr/share/sushi/js/viewers/text.js:33:7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `imports.gi.versions.GtkSource = "3.0";`

to the start of the file `/usr/share/sushi/js/viewers/text.js` fixed this for me.

See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/sushi/issues/12 and https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/59447

Comment: Thx, it works, so it's a bug?

Comment: @AlexTan Yes, I believe it's a bug.  The workaround is the 'easy fix' for now.

Answer (score 1):

The package `sushi` is for generic Desktop environements.

it works on unity and probably many others out of the box but for Gnome (like ubuntu 18 and 19 uses) you need to add the `gnome-sushi` package.

Comment: I install it via `apt install gnome-sushi`, and rebooted. When I press space button, nothing happen.

Comment: you need to reboot first.

Comment: I did reboot, still nothing

Comment: :( that's weird worked for me

Comment: @alex Please try pressing <Space> 4-5 times with 2-3 seconds gap between two key-presses and report back.

Comment: @pomsky nothing happen